# Spring Boot validation: get max size from property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have got a spring boot server and would like to validate my values by spring. Using the @Size validation I can set the max size. But i would like to get this max size from my application.property file.

I have already tried to load this value by "@Value(...)" but I can not use this value in the "@Size" field.

```java
 @Value("${max.size.in.properties}")
 private int MAX_SIZE;

@Size(max = 10)
private String description;
```

Comment: Can you make more specific, provide more details.

Answer (score 3):

The **bad news**: there's no way to do what you want with standard annotations from Java Validation API.

The **good news**: you can easily create a custom annotation that does exactly what you want.

You need to create a custom validation annotation (let's call it `@ConfigurableSize`) that takes as parameters two strings, one for the name of the property holding the min size and one for the name of the property holding the max size.

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(ConfigurableSize.List.class)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ConfigurableSizeCharSequenceValidator.class})
public @interface ConfigurableSize {

    String message() default "size is not valid";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String minProperty() default "";

    String maxProperty() default "";

    @Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        ConfigurableSize[] value();
    }

}
```

The validator will retrieve the property values upon initialization, then it will perform the exact same validation checks as the `@Size` constraint. Even the constraint violation will have the exact same message. Please notice that if the property name is omitted the `min` and `max` will default respectively to `0` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, i.e. the same defaults for `@Size`.

```
public class ConfigurableSizeCharSequenceValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ConfigurableSize, CharSequence> {

    private final PropertyResolver propertyResolver;
    private int min;
    private int max;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigurableSizeCharSequenceValidator(PropertyResolver propertyResolver) {
        this.propertyResolver = propertyResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableSize configurableSize) {
        String minProperty = configurableSize.minProperty();
        String maxProperty = configurableSize.maxProperty();
        this.min = "".equals(minProperty) ? 0 :
                propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(minProperty, Integer.class);
        this.max = "".equals(maxProperty) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE :
                propertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(maxProperty, Integer.class);
        validateParameters();
    }

    private void validateParameters() {
        if (this.min < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The min parameter cannot be negative.");
        } else if (this.max < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The max parameter cannot be negative.");
        } else if (this.max < this.min) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The length cannot be negative.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(CharSequence value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            int length = value.length();
            boolean retVal = length >= this.min && length <= this.max;
            if (!retVal) {
                HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateContext =
                        context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
                hibernateContext.addMessageParameter("min", this.min)
                        .addMessageParameter("max", this.max);
                hibernateContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                hibernateContext
                        .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}")
                        .addConstraintViolation();
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }

}
```

You apply the custom annotation in your bean

```
public class SomeBean {

    @ConfigurableSize(maxProperty = "max.size.in.properties")
    private String description;

}
```

Then finally in your `application.properties` you'll define the property

```
max.size.in.properties=10
```

And that's it. You can find more details and a full example in this blog post:
https://codemadeclear.com/index.php/2021/03/22/easily-configure-validators-via-properties-in-a-spring-boot-project/

Answer (score 1):

We can programmatically specify constraints [using Hibernate Validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api), which is already available in the classpath when using `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Given:

```java
 class MyObject {
     private String description;
     ...
 }
```

We can setup constraints like this:

```
@Value("${max.size.in.properties}")
private int MAX_SIZE;

HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation
                .byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
                .configure();
ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

constraintMapping.type( MyObject.class )
                 .property( "description", FIELD )
                 .constraint( new SizeDef().min( 1 ).max( MAX_SIZE ) );
```

and validate an instance of the object with:

```java
Validator validator = configuration.addMapping( constraintMapping )
                      .buildValidatorFactory()
                      .getValidator();

Set<ConstraintViolation<MyObject>> constraintViolations =
    validator.validate( myObjectInstance );

if (constraintViolations.size() > 0) {
   ... // handle constraint violations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this post per java reflection https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params

Comment: I do not believe that this will work. The annotation will not be evaluated upon every invocation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as annotations require constant expressions (`static final`) and `@Value` cannot be used to inject values into static final fields.

Maybe this project might help you out: https://github.com/jirutka/validator-spring.
It allows you to use Spring Expression Language together with bean validation.